# "Queue" without sequential order implications?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What word might I use that has the same connotations of "queue" but without the 1-by-1 implied order?

Example: an individual can make multiple changes to a series of items. Some changes may ultimately depend on another change, but all changes are made at once when complete. So they don't have to be recorded in order.

Comment: ..........list?

Comment: I need a word that is an action indicating input into - e.g., "queue changes" - "list", unfortunately, is an output action.

Comment: Ah, you're not talking about mainstream English. Then shouldn't this be asked on another SE site?

Comment: A queue without order is a crowd.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - there may be a better SE, but I'm unsure of it; apologies if I landed this is the wrong place.

Comment: Computational Science?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A group of items that are all processed together is called a **batch**.

From [Merriam Webster's:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/batch)

> 1. an amount of something that is made at one time
> 2. a group of people or things
> 3. computers : a set of jobs that a computer does together at one time